# How do I check whether an account is verified?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my check verified status code:

```
    <?

       $check = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email='$email' AND verified='1'";
       $mysqli->query($check);

          if($check = 1){

    } else {

          header('Location: fileadmin/not_activated.php');
    }

    ?>
```

I've already echoed the check,

`echo $check` shows 1 if verified.

`echo $check` shows 1 if not verified.

But `echo $check` should be 0 if not verified. Why isn’t it?

Comment: You have a few errors. `$check` is equal to the string of the query, not the result from the query for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($check = 1){
```

should be

```
if($check == 1){
```

Comment: Not sure how this is the answer. $check is set to his SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if($check = 1){
```

To this:

```
$result = mysqli->query($check);
if($result == 1){
```

It needs the double equals, and also assign $result to the database